# Create new column with conditions from other columns with strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a function that will create a new column based on certain conditions in two other columns in one pass. Here's a sample dataframe:

```
col_a    col_b    col_c
abc      abc      jkl
def      def      mno
ghi      pqr      pqr
```

So the resulting dataframe I would like is:

```
col_a    col_b    col_c   col_d
abc      abc      jkl     abc
def      def      mno     def
ghi      xyz      pqr     ghipqr
```

Assuming there are more columns and rows in this dataframe, I would like to create a function that if `col_a` == `col_b`, `col_d` == `col_a`. If `col_a` != `col_b`, then `col_d` = `col_a` + `col_c`. These columns are all strings.

I tried something like this:

```
list_1 = df['col_a']==df['col_b']

if list_1 is True:
    pass
elif list_1 is False:
    df['col_d'] = df['col_a'] + df['col_c']
```

But this didn't seem to work, and it added everything, regardless of if the condition was `True` or `False`. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['col_d'] = np.where(df.col_a==df.col_b, df.col_a, df.col_a+df.col_c)
```

or

```
df['col_d'] = df.col_a + np.where(df.col_a.eq(df.col_b), '', df.col_c)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use `pandas.Series.where` instead:

```
df["col_d"] = s.where(s.eq(df["col_b"]), s + df["col_c"])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col_a col_b col_c   col_d
0   abc   abc   jkl     abc
1   def   def   mno     def
2   ghi   pqr   pqr  ghipqr
```